# Promise for a void method

Tags: typescript, promise, void

I have a implemented a method to download a document into an Excel spreadsheet in Angular as below. Can someone please let me know how to implement promise for below `void` methods.

`ExportService` class:

```js
export class ExportService {

    constructor() { }

    fileType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
    fileExtension = '.xlsx';

    public exportExcel(jsonData: any[][], fileName: string): void {
        const x: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(jsonData[0]);
        const z: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(jsonData[1]);

        const b: XLSX.WorkBook = {
            Sheets: {
                'product': x,
                'sales': z
            },
            SheetNames: ['product', 'sales']
        };
        const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(b, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });

        this.saveExcelFile(excelBuffer, fileName);
    }

    private saveExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
        const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: this.fileType });
        FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + this.fileExtension);
    }
}
```

The export method in the component is as below.

```js
    export() {
        this.callProgress = true;
        this.progressText = "";
    
        this.salesProductForABC().then(() => {
            let products: Array<Array<any>> = [];
            products.push(this.productContent, this.salesProductContent);
    
            let month = new Date().getUTCMonth() + 1;
            let day = new Date().getUTCDate();
            let year = new Date().getUTCFullYear();
            let fileName = `${month}${day}${year}`;
            this.exportService.exportExcel(products, fileName)
            this.callProgress = false;
        })
      }
``

`
```

Comment: To make a void function return a promise (in other words, make `void` asynchronous function), make it's return type `Promise<void>`.  Which methods are you referring to?  `exportExcel` does not have any asynchronous code inside it (i.e. code using the `async`/`await` keywords).

Comment: @Hcaertnit Iam referring to methods in ExportService class.How can I implement then() in it?

Comment: @Hcaertnit The reason why i wanted to implement a promise is, I have implemented a loader in the above export() method But i want the loader to load until the excel sheet has finish downloading.

Answer (score 1):

1. Return promises from your service to be able to wait for them

Change

```
this.saveExcelFile(excelBuffer, fileName);
```

to

```
return this.saveExcelFile(excelBuffer, fileName);
```

and

```
FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + this.fileExtension);
```

to

```
return FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + this.fileExtension);
```

Of course, you will need to change `void` to returned type.

2. Make functions `exportExcel` and `saveExcelToFile` async to be able to wait for them

Eg.

```
public exportExcel(jsonData: any[][], fileName: string): void {
```

to

```
public async exportExcel(jsonData: any[][], fileName: string): Promise<void> {
```

3. Use finally and add error handling

Change

```
this.exportService.exportExcel(products, fileName)
this.callProgress = false;
```

to

```
this.exportService.exportExcel(products, fileName).catch(e => 
alert(e.message)).finally(() => this.callProgress = false;)
```

4. Add also error handling to `salesProductForABC` adding proper `catch`.

Lack of cathing errors in promises is really bad practice and leads to frustrating errors for users. Remember - in your code/infrastructure/input of the program, everything can be broken. It is important to do not leave:

- not returned promises
- unhandled exceptions

Finally, your code does not contain `FileSaver` but there probably you should return also promise, and there's also receptions that should be handled.